# Rails float month duration - NoMethodError: undefined method `months' for Float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can do `1.5.days`.

But how could I do `1.5.months`?

See my results in Rails console:

```
>> 1.5.days
=> 1.5 days
>> 1.5.months
NoMethodError: undefined method `months' for 1.5:Float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the deprecation warning [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Float/Time.html#M000996) (from Rails 2):

> ::ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(self.class.deprecated_method_warning(:months,
>   "**Fractional months are not respected. Convert value to integer before
>   calling #months.**"), caller)

It has now been **removed since Rails 3**.

If you view the original source, you'll see it was an unsatisfactory solution anyway:

`ActiveSupport::Duration.new(self * 30.days, [[:months, self]])`

You can extend the float class to allow this method:

```
# config/initializers/core_ext.rb

class Float
  def months
    ActiveSupport::Duration.new(self * 30.days, [[:months, self]])
  end
end
```

However, I'd advise against that. It was removed for a reason, likely quite problematic to implement.

Comment: Thanks, but ahving this: NoMethodError: undefined method `months_without_deprecation' for 1.5:Float.

Comment: @juanpastas: I'm afraid that was removed in `Rails 2.3`. Compare: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-3-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/float || https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/float. You could re-add the code via an initializer (I'll update my answer).